# Get an object of a dictionary by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dictionary:

```
[ object , object, object, object, object  ]
```

`object` contains: id and name.

I have an Id ('123456') and I want to get the object with this id.

Is there another solution how can I do it without for loop on the objects?

any help appreciated!

Comment: _without for loop_ forget it

Comment: What "other"? What solution do you already have?

Comment: Are there any specific reasons why you don't want to use for loops ?

Comment: Can you display 1 to 1000 without a loop..? :)

Comment: i don't think you can do this without loop i spent days searching for solution could't found one

Comment: You could use `filter` which gives the illusion of not being a loop, but that still loops over the data.

Comment: What's the intent behind the wish to not use a loop?

Comment: Do you mean without an *explicit* loop? I mean, you'll have to iterate over the data *somewhere*, unless you also keep a map/associative array/hash/whatever-you-want-to-call-it.

Comment: Hate `for` loop? Use `while`!

Comment: Why don't you use assoc. array notation e.g. `arr['key'] = 'value'` if you want to get objects by key?

Comment: Isn't finding clever coding techniques more on-topic for codegolf.stackexchange.com? SO is for _practical_ programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a vanilla JS method, you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). This pretty much does the same as [`$.grep`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).

```
var result = arr.filter(function (obj) {
  return obj.id === '123456';
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Hate `loops`, then go for `recursion`, i just assumed that you are having that array in a variable called as `xArr`

```
var xObj = check(0,"123456"); 

function check(cnt,id) {
 if(xArr[cnt].id === id)
  {
    return xArr[cnt];
  }
 else if(cnt === xArr.length - 1) {
    return null;
  }
 else {
    cnt += 1;
    return check(cnt, id);
  }    
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, because it's an interesting take on the problem, but personally I would have (a) made it more complete by passing in the id, (b) not used any globals because there's no reason to.

Answer (score 2):

That's an array, you could use `jQuery.grep` to get the elements with id `"123456"`.

```
var result = $.grep(arr, function(obj) {
  return obj.id === '123456';
});
```

Array also provide an `.filter` method (need a polyfill for browsers not support it):

```
var result = arr.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.id === '123456';
});
```

Comment: its a loop but with break and return condition

Comment: Yes, it internally uses loop. But gives the illusion that it doesn't :) still a good answer no doubt.

Comment: this is the only way to go to get this id .

Comment: I expect if you look under the hood of jQuery `$.grep` _is_ `filter`.

Comment: I've just noticed that the OP was against `for...loops`, so I've upvoted.